# What is the purpose of linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I know this is probably a stupid question but I am reading about linear transformations and while everything is pretty straightforward I still can't get what is the purpose of such transformations? Like why they are used in neural networks for example when we need to expand or reduce the dimensions of our input or output matrix. Is this why they are used? For dimensionality reduction which does not involve losing some portion of the data because it is linear? I have no math background so I might be using these terms incorrectly still it would be nice if someone could explain why do we need a linear transformation in the first place?

Comment: One solves easy problems before tackling hard ones, and once having solved an easy problem, we try to construe everything in the world to be an instance of what we already understand.  This has been going on for centuries, and possibly will continue well into the coming week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear transformation helps in following ways

1) Many observations in nature can be closely approximated to linear transformations. 
2) Reduces the complexity of the problem so that we can understand the relationship between the variables. 
3) Even nonlinear relationships can sometimes work well when they are closely approximated to linearly relationships.